# How to configure Jackson to control the behaviour of null fields?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

The class to which postman request body is mapped looks like this

```
public class RequestBody {
  String firstName;
  String middleName;
  String lastName;
}
```

postman request body looks like this
{
"firstName" : "somename"
}

Now my requirements are

1. When jackson is deserializing (From json to POJO), I want to map implicit and explicit null string values to " " (Empty string).
2. When jackson is serializing (From POJO to json), I want to map implicit and explicit null string values to " " (Empty string).

Problem I noticed is that when you implement jackson serialization and deserialization for String data type then it doesnt read explicit and implicit null values.

I tried Includes.ALWAYS but it didnt help to read implicit null values from json.

Comment: Probably custom [serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) / [deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).  How the customization is registered would depend on if the behavior is needed globally (all `String`s for all payloads) or just for those class fields mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`** & the default value.

ES:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RequestBody {
  String firstName = "";
  String middleName = "";
  String lastName = "";

 // Getter & Setter methods 

}
```